# media library thumbnails missing for txt and pdf

Tags: 7, media

The http://drupal.org/project/media module cannot display the thumbnails of txt and pdf files in my installation. I'm not expecting a thumbnail of the actual txt or pdf content of course but a generic placeholder.

**Display as list**:
[image: Display as list]

**Display as thumbnail**:
[image: Display as thumbnails]

Note that:

- no missing file (404) requests are being tracked in firebug
- this also affects the media popup file chooser from within content editing
- changing the theme doesn't solve this problem
- inspecting the "empty thumbnail" with firebug doesn't show anything useful, the `<a />` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `7.x-2.x-dev` instead of `7.x-1.1` solves this.

Answer (score 0):

I think we've had this problem before when people have the 'Styles' module enabled (and it's sub-module File styles). The use of those modules is now highly discouraged and they should be disabled if possible. I don't know if this is the case however here.

Comment: I do have `styles` and `file_styles` in my path but they are both disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the file type settings under configuration. If you click on the "File types" under the Media section you will see a list of default media types. The one you want to update is "Application (mulitpurpose)" or "Other". Click "Manage file display" and check the box next to Large filetype icon. You should do this at least for the "Preview" display. Save and reload and your problem should be cleared.